Swift 5: reflecting a Mirror children that is optional causes its properties to be empty
Reflecting and unwrapping optional works during unit testing, but not when running on the device in production even if the value is present, see the video:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/c8qb7nbcJB3SW4rSA
Basically the generic unwrapping is working on the mirror target object, but when we want to access the values of the object using the mirror children/descendant, they are empty.
Here is a simple illustration of this:
class MyTopLevelClass {
    @objc public var mySecondLevelClass?: MySecondLevelClass
    ...
}

class MySecondLevelClass {
    @objc public var myTargetProperty: String?
    ...
}
let mySecondLevelClass = MySecondLevelClass(myTargetProperty: "test")
let myTopLevelClass = MyTopLevelClass(mySecondLevelClass: mySecondLevelClass)
let mirrorTopLevel = Mirror(reflecting: myTopLevelClass)
let mirrorSecondLevel = flatten(Mirror(reflecting: 
mirrorTopLevel.descendant("mySecondLevelClass")))
print(mirrorSecondLevel.descendant("myTargetProperty"))
// print "" instead of "test" 

where the flatten function is a generic way of unwrapping the optional, see: https://forums.swift.org/t/challenge-flattening-nested-optionals/24083/2
Again, the flatten works in the unit test but not when running on the device for some reason. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Please post a version of this code that compiles and demonstrates the problem. This code has several syntax errors, and it's unclear what type you mean mirrorSecondLevel to be (it's currently Any?), plus there are warnings about some of the likely causes ("Expression implicitly coerced from Any? to Any.)
